# Copy n to m relation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

Suppose I habe two tables `recipient` and `list`.
`recipient` has the columns `id`, `email` and `customer`.
`list` has the columns `id`, `name` and `customer`.

Both tables are connected via `recipient_list` with the columns `recipient_id` and `list_id`.

In both `recipient` and `list` I have data for the `customer` "Demo customer" with appropriate entries in the join table.

What I'm trying to do now is to copy these entries **including** the relationship to another customer. I am aware I can insert data using a select using the following schema:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list)
SELECT 
   select_list 
FROM 
   another_table;
```

With this I can copy the entries of `recipient` and `list`. However this does not help me with duplicating the n-m relations. How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**
Here's a short example of what I like to achieve:

*Before:*

```
recipient
+----+------------------+---------------+
| id |      email       |   customer    |
+----+------------------+---------------+
|  1 | test@example.org | Demo Customer |
+----+------------------+---------------+
```

```
list
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id |   name    |   customer    |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | demo list | Demo Customer |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

```
recipient_list
+--------------+---------+
| recipient_id | list_id |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 |       1 |
+--------------+---------+
```

*After:*

```
recipient
+----+------------------+---------------+
| id |      email       |   customer    |
+----+------------------+---------------+
|  1 | test@example.org | Demo Customer |
|  2 | test@example.org | Real Customer |
+----+------------------+---------------+
```

```
list
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id |   name    |   customer    |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | demo list | Demo Customer |
|  2 | demo list | Real Customer |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

```
recipient_list
+--------------+---------+
| recipient_id | list_id |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 |       1 |
|            2 |       2 |
+--------------+---------+
```

Please note that the primary keys aren't necessarily as nice as in the example.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you want to get from it?

Answer (score 0):

The query to insert would be

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list)
SELECT 
   select_list 
FROM 
   another_table
WHERE customer = customer_name;
```

The "another_table" should be the join of recipient and list tables over customer_name. Taking join would eliminate the bad cases arising due to n-m relationship.